# Access data in json file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to using json data in my script. when I declare my var manually and check the console output

```
<script>
data = '[{"id": 1,"name": "Germany"},{"id": 2,"name": "Austria"},{"id": 3,"name": "USA"},{"id": 4,"name": "Australia"}]'; 
var countries = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(countries));
</script>
```

I get the data in this format.

[image]

Now I want to access to data from a json file, i took this [file](http://querybuilder.js.org/assets/demo-data.json) as an example and I am using this script to access to my data

```
<script>
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile("http://******/demo-data.json", function(text){
    var test1 = JSON.parse(text);
     console.log(test1);
    var test2 = JSON.stringify(text);
     console.log(test2);
});
</script>
```

It can see all the data but both formats are different to the one I want as you see here 
[image]

Any idea please how to read data from json file and when i use **console.log()** I will get the same format as the first example. Thank you very much.

Comment: `text` is already JSON, so calling `JSON.stringify`on it again is just going to cause issues. Did you mean to do `JSON.stringify(test1)` instead?

Comment: what is the goal ?

Comment: Simply `console.log(text)` would be the raw string version. I'm not sure why the difference matters though?

Comment: Both `test1` and `test2` look correct. Don't always rely on what you see in the console when dealing with strings.

Answer (score 0):

The *test1* is an object and *test2* is a string that's why you saw 2 different formats when *console.log()* is invoked.

If you want to console.log() always return object format then do not call *JSON.stringify(text)* because it will convert JSON object *text* to a string, *JSON.parse(text)* is enough since you need javascript object format.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you need to parse JSON first and then stringify the parsed json:

```
readTextFile("http://querybuilder.js.org/assets/demo-data.json", function(text){    
      var test1 = JSON.parse(text); //parse
      var test2 = JSON.stringify(test1); //stringfy the parsed json
      console.log(test2);
});
```

The output will be like:
[image]

Why you getting this:

You are getting JSON data as below, which is in formatted form

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Urna Ut PC"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Eu Augue LLC"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Commodo Auctor Consulting"
},
```

Instead if you receive json like below you will get your desired format:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Urna Ut PC"},{"id":2,"name":"Eu Augue LLC"},{"id":3,"name":"Commodo Auctor Consulting"},
```

You can view your incomming data format from the response tab of dev tool in browser.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the output as like the first example. To get output like the all the JSON data should be on one line.

Coming to your answer 
**To read JSON data you just need to parse that**

[Here is the solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/MNRbcyqPiTQ3zVwSXCRO) (I am mentioning this. So, you can copy the code easily)

As your JSON file is over **http**. So, it will not run on any https .

```
copy the code from https://plnkr.co/edit/MNRbcyqPiTQ3zVwSXCRO here and do run on your PC.
```

[image: This is what I got after running that same Code]